# MYSQL: Before Update Trigger not working for all queries

Tags: mysql

I have a table named as `doorshippers_products` I want to create a trigger that will set the `status` coulmn value to 1 when either `price` column or `stock` column's value get changed.
The problem is that I update 500 rows every minute, I noticed that the `price` and `stock` columns are changing but the `status` column is not changing for every row whose price or stock get changed.
Forexample the price changed for 500 coulmns but the status column was changed for only 200 or 300 coulmns.

I am new to coding please suggest an updated query to sort out this issue

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER `doorshippers_products_bu` 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `doorshippers_products` 
FOR EACH ROW
    set new.status = case when 
                            new.price != old.price OR new.stock != old.stock 
                          then 1 else 0 
                     end;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Updated:

I update only those rows through php script whose `status` coulmn's values are set to 0 here is that mysql query in php

```
$sql = "SELECT sku FROM doorshippers_products WHERE status=0 ORDER BY timestemp ASC LIMIT 10";
```

here is my Update query in php

```
$update = "UPDATE doorshippers_products  SET stock='".$stock."', price='".$price."', timestemp='".$time."' WHERE sku='".$sku."'";
```

Comment: Are the old or new values maybe `null`?

Comment: no. price is either 0.00 or greater

Comment: while stock is either 0 or 2

Comment: Another idea is that you maybe update the same row twice: once changing the values, the second time it doesnt (as they already have the new value).

Comment: No, I update only those rows from php whose status is set to 0.

Comment: Post your UPDATE query.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Well, we can assure you the trigger gets executed, you just have to figure out why your end result isn't the one you are expecting - but we don't know enough of your code to tell you where the problem is. Also, your comments don't rule out the double-update option, as sku might not be unique (although it probably is), or you may have several instances of your php script running (how is your script executed?) which, if run at the same time, each may select the same rows and double-update them. Maybe let your trigger insert old and new values into a log table to see what's going on.